# Microsoft graph user has a property createdDateTime but i cannot use it because user.cs has no property createdDateTime available

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the date when a user is created (createdDateTime) out of Microsoft graph User.

In Microsoft Graph Explorer you can find the property and it has a value.
But when I try to fill in my property in my c# code the microsoft.graph.user has no property `createdDateTime` of any sort so does it fall under something else or is not implemented yet?

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
                    {
                         new QueryOption("$select", "id,userPrincipalName,createdDateTime")
                    };

var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => { requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", BearerToken.access_token); return Task.FromResult(0); }));

var AllUsers = await graphserviceClient.Users.Request(options).GetAsync();

foreach ( Microsoft.Graph.User FoundUser in AllUsers)
                {
                    DateTimeOffset? cD = FoundUser.???//createdDateTime 
                }
```

in graph 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=displayName,createdDateTime

result

```
"displayName": "-K*** D****",
"createdDateTime": "2016-10-26T20:30:04Z"
```

expected:
I yust wane know where to get the value of this property that is stored in graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `createdDateTime` property is available within the `AdditionalData` Dictionary which is inside one of the parent class `Entity` that User inherits from.

> User : DirectoryObject : Entity

```
public IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalData { get; set; }
```

You will find it there.

Comment: thanks, is it documented somewhere? I couldn't find it in any official documentation